# Is it wasteful to commit unchanged objects to database with sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, database, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Let's say I have an object in memory from my database that I retrieved using sqlalchemy like this:

```
user_object = database_session.query(User).first()
```

I do a few checks on this object that don't change anything, like this (for this example my `user_object` has name property equal to "John"):

```
if user_object.name == "John": 
    do nothing
else:
    do something
```

I then add this object to a list that will get committed to the database at once, with this operation in mind:

```
objects_list.append(user_object)
database_session.add_all(objects_list)
database_session.commit()
```

Some of the objects in `objects_list` will have changes, some will not.

Is this process of committing a number of unchanged objects wasteful, and if so what is a better way to handle this situation?

Comment: Why are you adding unchanged items to the list at all?

Comment: I could use some kind of external flag to avoid adding unchanged items - the code is cleaner for my purposes to just add everything though, so I want to know whether sqlalchemy handles cases like this efficiently or if there is some better way than an external flag marking changed/unchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
user_object = database_session.query(User).first()
```

the loaded object is already in the session. From there on [the session tracks changes to the object](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#adding-and-updating-objects) through [instrumentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/glossary.html#term-instrumentation). [`Session.add()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.add) and [`Session.add_all()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.add_all) simply ignore objects that are already in the session, so

```
objects_list.append(user_object)
database_session.add_all(objects_list)
```

is at least partly redundant. When you call [`Session.commit()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.commit) SQLAlchemy will first flush any pending changes held in the `Session` to the database and then commits. In other words you're not committing any "unchanged objects".